# How to create wrapper holding of multiple properties in c#

Tags: c#

I want a wrapper whether it is class or any list type, to hold the multiple properties. I want to store the values of those properties and retrieve later. I created a class and doing some operations as below.

```
     internal class Dependencies
    {
        public string issueID;
        public int dependencyCheck;
        public string jirastatus;

        public Dependencies()
        {
            this.issueID = string.Empty;
            this.dependencyCheck = 0;
            this.jirastatus = string.Empty;
        }
//Calling this function.
preapreIssuesList(IssueKey, JIRAtoken);

 private static void preapreIssuesList(string IssueKey,string JIRAtoken)
        {
            Dependencies dependeant = new Dependencies();
            if (!dependeant.issueID.Contains(IssueKey))
            {
                dependeant.issueID = IssueKey;
                JiraSoapServiceService jira = new JiraSoapServiceService();
                RemoteIssue ri = jira.getIssue(JIRAtoken, (IssueKey).ToString());
                dependeant.jirastatus = Enum.GetName(typeof(GetChangesets.JIRAOperations.JIRAStatus), Convert.ToInt32(ri.status));
                dependeant.dependencyCheck = 0;
            }
            else if (dependeant.issueID.Contains(IssueKey))
            {
                dependeant.dependencyCheck = 1;
            }

        }
```

If I do like this, will it hold the stored values? Or is it better to take `Dependencies` of `List<>` type? 
Can any one suggest me answer?

Comment: Why -1 any wrong in that... strange.. :)

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see, it will not store any information about your `Dependencies` objects. After they are created in `prepareIssuesList`, they go out of scope and then the garbage collecter will dispose of them.

You need to keep a reference to them somewhere to keep that information. Maybe `prepareIssuesList` should return the `Dependencies` object that it creates, and whatever is calling that method can store the object?

As an aside, your code above will not compile - the call to `prepareIssuesList` is made within a class body, and the compiler thinks it is a method declaration. Also, your class is called `Dependencies` but seems to describe a single item, so maybe `Dependency` would be a better name?

Comment: Thanks for you information... I can't get you what you are saying exactly. I dont know much c#, can you provide me the solution for above code?

Comment: Well, I'll need a bit more information - what sort of application are you creating, and what is this doing?

Comment: Creating windows application. I want to store three properties as issueid as string ,dependency_check as int, status as string.

Comment: Only one lot of three values, or are there many many sets of these three values to store?

Comment: i will call a one method and there i will assign new values to those three variables. so it can store multiple sets of 3 values